# Store text in database in some languages

Tags: mysql, sql, database, unicode

Can anyone tell me how can i store for example russian words in database? Please write an example. I know that i must use unicode, but don't know how use with mySql.

Thanks all for response.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a database with utf8 character set and russian collation.
Find the russian collation:

```
SHOW COLLATION LIKE '%russian%'
```

Then create the database:

```
CREATE DATABASE db_name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE latin1_russian_ci;
```

You can also ALTER it if you already have one.
Read the manual here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-database.html